# Conveniently export part of Google spreadsheet to HTML page

Tags: google-sheets

Google spreadsheet allows you to save the table as HTML:

[image: save google spreadsheet as HTML]

The problem is that what the HTML you get is not publishable in website or coherent HTML document:

[image: exported google spreadsheet]

I'd just like a part of the table as HTML. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free online service called `tableizer`. You can select a rectangular data area you want inside google sheets (or other spreadsheet applications) and copy-paste it into the input field of the service:

http://tableizer.journalistopia.com/

You receive a basic HTML table source code with your data in it. You can insert the code into an HTML page that you control.

It comes with basic CSS so you can style it to your desire.

If you need to create an html page from it, you have to follow some simple steps:

Open a source code editor and insert this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Insert the resulting code from `tableizer` by pasting it where the empty line is between `<body>` and `</body>`.

Save the document with an `html` ending, like `page.html` and open the resulting document with your browser to see the result.

Comment: The tableizer link is awesome.

Comment: This is not really the answer I hoped for, since it depends on a service that can go down any time. There's also always risk that the service will steal the data pasted into it. However, it solves the problem and is compatible with other programs as well, so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by using the google visualizations API to query data in a publically shared google sheet and draw a chart from the data. Outputting just the table of data should be that much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your documents holds data that you do not want to share.

So I would :

1. add a sheet "public" in which I would copy/paste the data
2. use the built-in "publish for the web" functionality
   [image]
3. in the "publish" dialog, limit the publication to the "public" worksheet

Note that, instead of copy/paste (annoying if the data changes frequently) you can use the [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sheet and copy the section you want to display into this new sheet. Make sure you use "paste special" to copy formula and that the formula you are copying uses the full cell reference with the sheet name (like 'Sheet 1'!A:A) in order to make the cells in the new sheet point to the cells in the original sheet so that when the original cells are updated, the cells in the new sheet will follow them.  Now click on "File" --> "Publish to the web". Now choose "embed" and choose the new sheet. Make sure the "Automatically republish when changes are made" is ticked.

Here is an example of this in action:

https://mikeostest.wixsite.com/content